# Nuxt3 + Cypress: "useI18n is not defined" error in component testing

Tags: vuejs3, internationalization, cypress, nuxt3

I'm currently working on testing Vue components in Nuxt 3 using Cypress. I have a modal component (SharedModalDefault.vue) that I'm trying to test with the following Cypress code:

```
import SharedModalDefault from "/components/Shared/Modal/SharedModalDefault.vue"

describe('Modal Component Test', () => {
  it('should render a modal with default props', () => {
    cy.mount(SharedModalDefault, {
      props: {
        show: true,
        title: 'Modal Title',
        text: 'Modal Text',
        size: 'xl',
      },
    })

    cy.get('[role="dialog"]').should('exist')
  })
})
```

However, when I run this test, I'm encountering the following error:

`useI18n is not defined`

I've double-checked that vue-i18n is properly installed in my project and set up in nuxt.config.js. The module is working properly in my component using `const {t} = useI18n()` without a specific import.

Is there something I'm missing in the setup or is there a specific configuration needed for vue-i18n in Cypress tests with Nuxt3?

Any help or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

**Update**

When I add useI18n to the window, it supresses the error:

```
cy.window().then((win) => {
    win.useI18n = () => ({
        t: (key: string) => key, // Mocking the t function
    })
})
```

However, this will jump to the next one: `useSlots()`, then to `computed()`, and so on.

What is the proper way to deal with these auto imports?

Comment: can you please share where you've imported the library? main.js?

Comment: are you using `@` as an import alias for something like `src`?

Answer (score 3):

Try following the Vue example at [Replicating plugins](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/component-testing/vue/examples#Replicating-Plugins)

The docs say there isn't yet support for Nuxt3, but you could get some functionality testing by adding the libraries into a custom `cy.mount()` as shown.

This is in `cypress/support/component.js` which is the test equivalent to main in your app.

```js
import { createPinia } from 'pinia' // or Vuex
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n'
import { mount } from 'cypress/vue'
import { h } from 'vue'

// We recommend that you pull this out
// into a constants file that you share with
// your main.js file.
const i18nOptions = {
  locale: 'en',
  messages: {
    en: {
      hello: 'hello!',
    },
    ja: {
      hello: 'こんにちは！',
    },
  },
}

Cypress.Commands.add('mount', (component, ...args) => {
  args.global = args.global || {}
  args.global.plugins = args.global.plugins || []
  args.global.plugins.push(createPinia())
  args.global.plugins.push(createI18n())

  return mount(() => {
    return h(VApp, {}, component)
  }, ...args)
})
```